# Xamarin Label Click change Checkbox State Only Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change the state of a Checkbox in Xamairn.

My Xaml Code

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox VerticalOptions="Start"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CheckBox.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,-10,0,0" />
                <On Platform="Android, WinPhone, Windows" Value="0,-5,0,0" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </CheckBox.Margin>
    </CheckBox>
    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"
        Text="{Binding Text}">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer>

            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

I know I have done this before but I forgot.

I have to add a setter or something in the TapGestureRecognizer to make the Checkbox IsChecked=True
and IsChecked=False when its True

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do it in an MVVM way what you are looking for is the `Command`.

In your ViewModel add the command:

```
public ICommand ChangeStateCommand { get; set; }
```

and in the Constructor initialize it:

```
ChangeStateCommand = new Command(() => IsChecked = !IsChecked);
```

Then you will need to bind it with the  `TapGestureRecognizer` of your `Label`.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <CheckBox VerticalOptions="Start"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CheckBox.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,-10,0,0" />
                <On Platform="Android, WinPhone, Windows" Value="0,-5,0,0" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </CheckBox.Margin>
    </CheckBox>
    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"
                                           Text="{Binding Text}" >
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ChangeStateCommand}" />
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to checkBox and a tapEvent to label, then change the isChecked property in code behind:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox VerticalOptions="Start" x:Name="myCheckBox"
    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CheckBox.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,-10,0,0" />
                <On Platform="Android, WinPhone, Windows" Value="0,-5,0,0" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </CheckBox.Margin>
    </CheckBox>
    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"
    Text="{Binding Text}">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myCheckBox.IsChecked = !myCheckBox.IsChecked;

    //or change the IsChecked property in ViewModel
    //myViewModel.IsChecked = !myViewModel.IsChecked;
}
```

Comment: Now Imagine if I have 10s of those in a List now that would be very bad

Comment: You did not mention a list in your question and if so, a command may work and change the corresponding IsChecked property in model.